# Como salvar um arquivo no Vim

Tags: cron, vim

Eu estou me conectando na hospedagem da UOL por SSH para fazer agendar uma tarefa com o cron. Eu consigo digitar o agendamento, só que não sei como salvar, dar um `CTRL+S` no terminal creio que não funciona e não sei qual comando usar. A tela  do terminal fica mais ou menos assim (é o Vim?):

```
55 23 * * * curl www.meusite.com.br/cron...
~
~
~
~
~
~
-- INSERT --
```

E quando digito não sei como dar um *save*.

Comment: basta fazer isso: `[esc] :w!` Se quiser sair ao mesmo tempo que grava: `[esc] :wq!`

Answer (score 1):

Pressione ESC e digite `:w` para salvar ou `:x` para salvar e sair

Answer (score 1):

**@RESOLVIDO**

Apenas digitei a tarefa cron, depois apertei **esc** e digitei **:wq**